# enum in a struct; newbie in a c

Tags: c, pointers, enums, struct, adt

I'm wondering about the syntax of using an `enum` in a `struct` (*in `C`*)

I've seen various examples where a `struct` + `union`/`enum` combination was used to create a complex type, for example:

```
struct MyStruct{
    enum{
        TYPE_1,
        TYPE_2,
        TYPE_3,
    } type;
    union{
        int value_1;
        int value_2;
        int value_3;
    } value;
};

// ...

struct MyStruct test_struct;
```

Anyways, from this example, how would I store/test the current "type" as per the `enum` field?

If I have a pointer to `test_struct`, this doesn't seem to work; kicking back an unknown member error:

```
struct MyStruct *test_pointer = &test_struct;

test_pointer->value = test_pointer->VALUE_1;
```

I'm just curious, do I need to access the `enum` values as global values?

```
test_pointer->value = VALUE_1;
```

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The intended usage of such a struct would be something like that:

```
switch (test_struct.type) {
  case TYPE_1:
    printf("%d", test_struct.value.value_1);
    break;

  case TYPE_2:
    printf("%d", test_struct.value.value_2);
    break;

  case TYPE_3:
    printf("%d", test_struct.value.value_3);
    break;
}
```

Note that capitalising `VALUE_1`, `VALUE_2` and `VALUE_3` is incorrect because they are not constants but rather members of the union.

`TYPE_1`, `TYPE_2` and `TYPE_3` will be globally accessible, no matter that the corresponding `enum` resides in the struct.

Comment: Thanks **Blagovest Buyukliev**; So when addressing one of the enumerated values, you do so as a global identifier, not a member of the `struct` in which it resides? The reason for this question is, I figured by wrapping the `enum` within the `struct`, one could avoid polluting the namespace, so to speak; accessing the enumerated values as members of the `struct`. Is this not possible?

Comment: Also, oops on the `VALUE_1`, etc., I don't typically do that :P

Comment: +1, but I think that the usual convention is capitalization only for macros, nothing to do wether or not they represent constants. In that sense `TYPE_...` are also "incorrect".

Comment: @TomcatExodus: No, C is a bit crummy and doesn't provide separate namespaces for the enums, unlike Java and C#.

Comment: **@Jens Gustedt**; Strange, in all my reading, every example of enumerated value names were capitalized.

Comment: **@Blagovest Buyukliev**: Aw, darn. However, that answers my question, so thank you!

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, Capitalisation of constants is a long standing practice, not just in C. I dare say it's even done far more often than not. I'm not sure how you avoided being exposed to this.

Answer (score 1):

What happens with a union is that all objects defined therein occupy the same memory. And it's illegal to read an object different than the last written one.

In

```
union blah {
    int bleh;
    double blih;
    char bloh[42];
};
union blah myobject;
```

`myobject` contains one of `int`, `double`, or `char[]`. And there is no indication which one is correct. The indication must be kept somewhere else by the programmer:

```
int lastblahwrite; /* 0: int; 1: double; 2: char[] */
strcpy(myobject.bloh, "The quick brown dog");
lastblahwrite = 2;
```

and later this could be used as

```
switch (lastblahwrite) {
    case 0: printf("%d\n", myobject.bleh); break;
    case 1: printf("%f\n", myobject.blih); break;
    case 2: printf("%s\n", myobject.bloh); break;
    default: assert(!"this didn't happen"); break;
}
```

Rather than have two separate variables, to make management easier, it is usual to group the union itself and the indicator variable in a struct, as in your example.

The management still has to be written by the programmer. Nothing is automatic.

Comment: Thank **pmg**; I gathered the reason for creating a `struct` in such a fashion, however the syntax for accessing enumerated values within a `struct` eluded me. It's unfortunate that, as **Blagovest** pointed out, `C` does not permit accessing the enumerated values as members of the `struct`.