# Assign enum(declared inside a struct) value to a variable of the same enum type inside the struct

Tags: c++, c, struct, enums

I have a structure of below type

```
struct enumStruct
{
    enum Number
    {
        zero = 0,
        one = 1
    };

    Number t;

    union
    {
        /* t = 0 */
        some_struct_zero zero;
        /* t = 1 */
        some_struct_one one;
    } un;
} v_enumStruct;
```

Can I assign a value to `v_enumStruct.t` as below?

```
v_enumStruct.t = v_enumStruct.zero;//Option 1
```

Also, the below does not seem to work

```
v_enumStruct.t = zero; //Option 2 - zero is mistaken as an unavailable variable name
```

Comment: My guess would be "no". Did you try it? What did the compiler think?

Comment: I tried and option 1 worked!

Comment: If anything worked like you show it here, there are good chances that you are compiling this as C++ and not as C. These are two different languages.

Comment: It is indeed a cpp header. So, should I understand this may not have worked in C then?

Answer (score 1):

1) `zero` is not a member of `struct`. 2) The `enum` inside `struct` doesn't declare any member. It can be declared anywhere. enum members are named constants, they are not variables and  3) `Number` needs the `enum` qualifier:

```
    struct enumStruct
    {
        enum Number
        {
            zero = 0,
            one = 1
        };
        enum Number t;

        union
        {
         /* t = 0 */
         some_struct_zero zero;
         /* t = 1 */
        some_struct_one one;
        } un;

} v_enumStruct;
```

You might as well move the `enum Number { ..};` outside the `struct` as it's not doing anything inside the struct. Now you should be able to assign:

```
v_enumStruct.t = zero;
```

Comment: But zero is considered as enum value right? So, ideally the enum inside struct should have been ok to be used globally too? Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902744/enum-in-a-struct-newbie-in-a-c

Comment: Having enum as *member of sturct*  is OK. If you look at the linked post carefully, it declares `type` as member of struct MyStruct. An equivalent change to your code would be: `enum Number { zero = 0, one =1 }t;`